Optimal way to outline an irregular shape / fractal
I have been looking into the coastline paradox in determining the "length" of non self-similar fractals, such as the coastline of countries.
As shown in the image, the coastline will change depending on the "ruler" or "yardstick", the unit length used to approximate the contour, such than an even yet irregular polygon is formed.
Now, my question regards how the placement of such rulers are optimised: or rather what programme / mathematical technique were imposed to guarantee a suitable result? Lets say I am trying to measure Britan's coastline with a "10 km" ruler. In what way and how many should they be placed? Or have I completely misunderstood the approach, and should have rather defined N set points, each evenly apart?


What exactly do you mean by a "suitable result"? The point of this thought-experiment isn't really to actually measure the coastline, it's to understand that some shapes that enclose finite areas can have arbitrarily long perimeters. The ruler is just a way to illustrate that (and in particular, that these shapes aren't obscure mathematical constructs; they can be quite familiar). Contrast this to the same idea but applied to an ellipse. Shortening the ruler increases the measured length, but this time the length tends to a finite limit.

@ChrisLewis Yes, I understand that. This is actually for a project. What I mean is that I would actually need to measure the area, and moving the "rulers" would cause changes in the area. So what I need to achieve is to find the most suitable placements of rules to form an area most similar to the actual, theoretical area. Hope that makes sense.

In your question, you're asking about lengths, but in your comment you're asking about areas. Either way, there isn't going to be a general answer for all shapes, but area might be a bit easier. Probably the best you can do is write an algorithm to step around the perimeter of your shape using a fixed step length and start point, then investigate what happens to your result as you change the position of the start point slowly around the coast. As you move the start point around, you'll start to repeat configurations, so you can stop scanning there. For the area, you want the smallest result.

@ChrisLewis The idea was to find the perimeter then to calculate the area. Your proposition sounds sensible, thank you!
